# Hide row if ACF sub field is checked

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, checkbox, advanced-custom-fields

I got a ACF Reaper field with a couple of rows I am trying to show. However, I only want the show row if it has a checkbox checked (Checkbox is a subfield within the repeater). I am trying to accomplish that by using if in_array as described in [ACF documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/checkbox/) under "Conditional logic":

`if( in_array( "bestyrelsevalg", get_sub_field( 'bestyrelse' ) ) )`

I am outputting the result in a WordPress shortcode. For now, my code kinda works, except it shows all results within the repeater field (also those that are unchecked). What am I missing ??

**My code:**

```
function investor_bestyrelse_shortcode() {
$rows = get_field('budgetter_og_nyhedsbreve');

if( $rows  ) {
    echo '<ul class="slides">';
    foreach( $rows as $row ) {
if( in_array( "bestyrelsevalg", get_sub_field( 'bestyrelse' ) ) ) {
        $image = $row['upload_dokument'];
        echo '<li>';
            echo get_field( 'upload_dokument' );
        echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}   

}

add_shortcode( 'investor_bestyrelse', 'investor_bestyrelse_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve issue and with the help from @maggiathor's answer. For some reason echo was causing issue. I had to use return insted:

```
function investor_bestyrelse_shortcode() {
            $rows = get_field('budgetter_og_nyhedsbreve');
    if( $rows  ) {
        $content = '<ul class="dokumenter">';
            foreach( $rows as $row ) {
            if( !in_array( "bestyrelsevalg", $row['bestyrelse'] ) ) {
                $pdf = $row['upload_dokument'];
                
                $content = $content . '<li>' . $pdf . '</li>';
            }
            }
        }
        $content = $content . '</ul>';
        return $content;
    }   
add_shortcode( 'investor_bestyrelse', 'investor_bestyrelse_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use get_sub_field() within the foreach loop, either you need to use a have_rows-while-loop or access it from the associative array:

```
function investor_bestyrelse_shortcode() {
    $rows = get_field('budgetter_og_nyhedsbreve');
    if( $rows  ) {
        echo '<ul class="slides">';
            foreach( $rows as $row ) {
                if( in_array( "bestyrelsevalg", $row['bestyrelse'] ) ) {
                $image = $row['upload_dokument'];
                echo '<li>';
                echo $row['upload_dokument'];
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }   
}
add_shortcode( 'investor_bestyrelse', 'investor_bestyrelse_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. However, still the same: shows all results within the repeater field (also those that are unchecked). Btw. there is a syntax error in code. Missing semicolon at the end of add_shortcode();

Comment: Okay, You can run var_dump($row); at the start of the loop to see how the array looks like, maybe there is a typo or something like that.

Comment: Having no luck with var_dump - Not sure if I'm doing it right since it's in a loop. I was also reading the ACF Repeater documentation and saw they are not using get_field for repeater fields but insted have_row(); - Maybe I should change code a bit? Documentation: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Comment: foreach is fine and works to – another issue could be that the shortcode doesn't run on the post you want. You might check echo get_the_id(); if it's the right post. If not you need to pass the postId into the get_field('key', $postid); function.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, @maggiathor. I did find the solution and posted answer in this thread :)